# Random Word8 duplicate instance declaration during cabal testpack installation

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, hunit

What does the following error message mean when `cabal install testpack-2.1.1` has failed:

```
... Everything above this succeeded with no problems.
[22 of 22] Compiling Control.Monad.Cont ( Control/Monad/Cont.hs, dist/build/Control/Monad/Cont.o )
Registering mtl-2.2.1...
Installing library in /home/ely/.cabal/lib/mtl-2.2.1/ghc-7.4.2
Registering mtl-2.2.1...
Downloading testpack-2.1.1...
Configuring testpack-2.1.1...
Building testpack-2.1.1...
Preprocessing library testpack-2.1.1...
[1 of 3] Compiling Test.QuickCheck.Instances ( src/Test/QuickCheck/Instances.hs, dist/build/Test/QuickCheck/Instances.o )

src/Test/QuickCheck/Instances.hs:50:10:
    Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance Random Word8
        -- Defined at src/Test/QuickCheck/Instances.hs:50:10
      instance Random Word8 -- Defined in `System.Random'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
testpack-2.1.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I've tried Googling, but cannot make sense of this install error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`testpack-2.1.1` provides a so called *orphan* instance for `Random Word8`, that is, an instance where it doesn't define either the class or the type itself.

One of the several problems with orphan instances is that one of the packages which *do* define the class or type might choose to add that instance themselves in a later version, which is precisely what the `random` package has done in this case, and so the instances conflict.

From `testpack` version `2.1.2` there is a check that makes sure to only define the instance if the `random` package is too old to have done so itself. So you should be able to fix this by installing a later version of `testpack` instead.

Comment: I will work on this, but a quick attempt at `cabal install testpack-2.1.2` gave this error almost immediately: `src/Test/QuickCheck/Tools.hs:34:34: 'interrupted' is not a (visible) field of constructor 'MkResult'`

Comment: @EMS Sheesh. Anyway, I tried just `cabal install testpack` myself, and it installed 2.1.2.1 with only some warnings. Then I realized I should have done `cabal update`, and after that it ...erred out when trying to install 2.1.3.0. Something tells me the version bounds on that package are not well-written :(